# systemctl daemon-reload after installation of rpm

Tags: rpm, systemd

I created an RPM with nfpm. When the RPM is installed on an OEL 7.x system, it requires me to reload the unit files, before I can start the service.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

How would I do allow the RPM to reload, so that the service can be started, and also be enabled on reboots?

Since this may be nfpm config (YAML) specific, I wouldn't mind the native RPM spec file perspective either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just one comment, if I see tags pertaining to my question that would lead me into thinking I can post here. However, if you're saying ignore the tags, and just post *anything* pertaining to Linux/Utils then I will do that. Just confusing why you'd allow those tags here to begin with.

Comment: Hover over the tag and you will see why it's off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could put that in the `%post` section:

```
%post
systemctl daemon-reload
```

While we are at it, here are some good practices that I found for cleanup when your package is uninstalled:

```
%preun
if [ $1 == 0 ]; then #uninstall
  systemctl unmask %{name}.service
  systemctl stop %{name}.service
  systemctl disable %{name}.service
fi

%postun
if [ $1 == 0 ]; then #uninstall
  systemctl daemon-reload
  systemctl reset-failed
fi
```